# Firebase functions - how to set type to FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is probably stupid question, but how can I set type for for collection().get() in firestore functions?

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as WineModel from '../../src/app/tasting/wine/wine.model';

admin.initializeApp();

export const countGlogStat = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const wines: WineModel.WineModel[] = [];
    try {
        const winesSnapshots = await admin.firestore().collection('wines').get();
        winesSnapshots.forEach(wineSnapshot => wines.push(wineSnapshot.data()));
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('Error while getting wines', err);
        res.status(500).json({
            custName: 'Error while getting wines',
            err 
        });
    }  
});
```

I am getting error:
Argument of type 'DocumentData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WineModel'.
Property 'wineRating' is missing in type 'DocumentData' but required in type 'WineModel'.

Thank you very much help!!!! :-)

Comment: I don't see that you're using `WineModel` or property `wineRating` anywhere in your code (other than import).  Are you sure the error refers to this exact code?

Comment: Ups sorry :-) ...fixed. It is interface used in const wines ....

Comment: You're going to have to write code to create a new WineModel type object (whatever that looks like), and copy data into it from the snapshot (whatever that looks like).

Comment: Sorry for my late response (i was sick). My Angular app creating wine in structure defined by WineModel interface. Right now I am trying to do some calculation on backend (so firebase functions). But I will love to have some autocopletion so Im traing to define for my const wines :-).